# Getting next specific value appearance in an array in PHP

Tags: php

I having difficulties to get the next specific value from an array.

```
 while (list($index, $day) = each($user['days'])) {

 }
```

in `$user['days]` I have all of the date from a specific month in the key and in the value i have to type of values: 480 or 4 K .
for instance:

```
 $user[1] = 480
 $user[2] = 480
 $user[3] = 4 K
......
 $user[25] = 4 K
 $user[26] = 480
.....
 $user[30] = 4 K
```

so If I have two 4 K , the first will become 480 and next will become 8 F
if I have 4 of 4 K I will have two 480 and two 8 F 
and if in the final it remains a 4 K I have to change on the next month to become 8 F and in the current month should remain 480. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: not really, Im out of idea. can you help me ? I have to group them somehow

Comment: With such questions always show your real input, and the desired (maybe handcrafted) output. Following a text-explanation is most often harder than simply "seeing" what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost did not understand, but maybe this function help you

```
array_keys ( $user, '4 K');
```

it will return array  (3,25,30). It's length gives you a count of '4 K', and values will be the keys of user array